# add querystring parameter in URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net mvc.

here I am not asking on controller logic but at view page.And I am not messing with default setting of url routing.

I have a view having some url like /controller/action?CID=2

In this view I want to put Link having above structure but with different controller.

The point is get the current url parameter and put hyperlink with same Querystring parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("linkText", "actionName", 
    "controllerName", new {CID = Request.QueryString["CID"]}, null) %>
```

Do you mean something like this?

Comment: Is this an "okay" thing to do in MVC? I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm just interested to know.

Comment: Actually your url format is not registered in my routing table. so I explicitly pass it like ?CID=1

Comment: The third parameter on this overload is routeValues, and a custom object like the one above is usually what's used for this purpose (passing parameters for the route).

Comment: @Vikas
My url format? I just put them in there for demonstration. You, of course, need to replace them with your values.

Comment: I'm Trying to say that CID is not registered. If you registered a path with parameter as ID then you must have to pass a parameter with name ID. In my case it is CID & registered as ID

Comment: Ok it's working! Thanks and sorry for commenting without checking